# Getting API data + Optional Problems

Tags: ios, json, api, post, option-type

I'm struggling to get an optional type to a Label.text. It keeps on giving me "nil" value and won't change the text.

```
import UIKit

class VerifyPNViewController: UIViewController {

    
    @IBOutlet weak var VerificationMessage: UILabel!
    
    @IBAction func backButton(_ sender: Any) {
        self.view.window!.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        

    }
    
    func didSuccess(_ response: GetLoginVerificationMessage){
        let Main = response.result!
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                print(Main)
                self.VerificationMessage?.text = Main
                print(self.VerificationMessage?.text)
            }
    }
}
```

and I will get a

234443 << which is a response.result!

nil << print(self.VerificationMessage?.text)

I have no idea why this value won't go into the "self. Verification?.text" Does anyone have ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you check that `self.VerificationMessage` is not nil? Because that would mean that you are not storing your value anywhere.

Comment: Yes, what happens if you say `self.VerificationMessage.text = Main`?  Did you connect the outlet?  By the way, by convention variables start with a lower case letter and classes start with an upper case letter

Comment: @MaticOblak I do believe it is not nil because i have connected to the outlet. Will this make the value not nil?

Comment: @Paulw11 self.VerificationMessage.text = Main? << this was supposed to change the label's text and yes, i have connected the outlet but still getting nil when i'm putting Main to "self.VerificationMessage?.text". 
P.S Thank you for the advice of naming the variables and classes. New to programming

Comment: Make sure that you place a breakpoint and check what is going on. A useful tool that you have (once hitting a breakpoint) is you can use a debugger section (the console part usually found in bottom right section of Xcode) and use `po [expression]` which means "print object". Use it like `po self.VerificationMessage` and confirm that it is non-nil. There are other reasons for it to be `nil` next to not connecting the outlet.

Comment: Another common mistake is not creating your view controller instance from the storyboard.  Is this your initial view controller? How is it created?